# Оставить тень только по бокам

Tags: css

В приведённом примере тень блока со всех сторон.
Подскажите, как сделать такую же тень, но только чтобы тень была только по бокам?

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 55px 4px rgba(0,2,3,.05);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body{
  background: #fff;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px 50px;
  position: relative;
  /*box-shadow: 0 0 55px 4px rgba(0,2,3,.05);*/
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 55px;
  height: 100%;
}

div:before {
  right: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset -55px 0 55px -55px rgba(0,2,3,.15);
}
div:after {
  left: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 55px 0 55px -55px rgba(0,2,3,.15);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div{
 width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px 50px;
  box-shadow:
   0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3),
   -23px 0 20px -23px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8),
   23px 0 20px -23px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8),
   0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) inset;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```